# Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bookmarks

I have been using Stack Overflow for a while now and realized what a great source of knowledge the answers are across many topics.

In many cases, I thought that it would be useful to have the option to save some questions and their answers in a special "list". Later, I could visit this list and read again the answers I got before making a decision.

Are there any plans that will allow users the ability to save answers and/or questions in a list?

Answer (score 9):

If you click the star below the voting section on a question (to the left of the question), it will be saved to your favourites. You can then keep track of all the questions and their answers as they will be saved on the Favorites tab in your account.

[image: favorite]
<sup>screenshot from [Dariusz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/209448/dariusz) found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214758)</sup>

Comment: i cannot see a star under the voting question...Do you mean for questions that i have submitted/asked ?

Comment: You should see the little star on the left of a question. Click that and it will glow. That means it's been saved to your favourites list.

Comment: @unknown: It under the votes for the question specifically, not the answer.

Comment: So many spiders crawling on the page.

Comment: @random I replaced the image that was hosted on imageshack as that one went 404. If you happen to have the original or want to create a new one you can upload it and replace what have edit in for now

Comment: Quick note - since this was posted, 'favourites' became 'bookmarks' and is now 'saves'

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022 - there's 2 mechanisms to do so.

[image]

You can follow a post or  save it

Follows treats a question like 'one of your own' - you get notifications of new answers and comments.

While its a nascent feature - and there may be more to come, [saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves)

[image]

Saves lets you organise things into lists and add annotations to the posts, which is useful for say you need to create a list for a project.

Answer (score 1):

Taking this a logical step further, let's say you are really more interested in a specific answer than the question itself. S[OFU] doesn't need a new feature for you to manage this; you already have it: Your browser's bookmarks or favorites list. You can create folders, organize as needed, and have everything you need just a click or two away at any time.

Comment: that is a non-solution. I will have to sync my browser bookmarks across different computers - home, work, etc.. Now please don't suggest to use a tool to keep bookmarks in Sync :-)