# Any way to save a question (like in Reddit)

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. If so, maybe it should be made more visible in the UI.

Is there any way to "save" a question I like so that I can come back later to either check new responses or to refer to after a few months etc. Kinda like an in-site bookmark facility like what Reddit has.

Any plans to add something like this?

Comment: This kind of questions *about* http://stackoverflow.com belong on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 7):

You can mark a question as a "favorite" by clicking the star underneath the vote count.

Comment: I didn't realize that the favorite button was intended to be used as bookmarks, that's ingenious! Thank you.