# Save questions to visit later, but not exactly 'favourite' them

Tags: feature-request, questions, bookmarks

Most of the time I find questions that I would want to log in later to answer. These wouldn't exactly be my favorite questions since that's not the intent. Would it be possible to create such a feature. This is not a duplicate of [Any way to save a question (like in Reddit)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25514/any-way-to-save-a-question-like-in-reddit).

Currently I would need to "favorite" a question and then remember to un-"favorite" it later. This 'visit-later' list can be autopurged after 10-20 questions or so.

I do know that most questions would've been answered on SO by the time I come back home and login, but still..

Comment: I've asked a similar question.  See the answers here: [Add "Answer Later" Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/add-answer-later-tab)

Comment: A year later, and no such feature :(

Comment: Isn't the RSS feed for each question sufficient?

Comment: I am also really missing an option like this, what can we do about it/who decides to add this feature?

Comment: I would also like to be able to add *answers* and *comments* in addition to *questions* to a "view later" queue.

Comment: i was about to ask the same ......

Comment: I've marked this question as a favorite and hope to revisit later to see that it was implemented ;-) An ideal compromise solution might be to allow notes on favorites, similar to how Amazon Wish List works...

Comment: This is what browser tabs are for.  (Use OneTab or equivalent if you don't like leaving lots of tabs open to come back to later.)

Answer (score 8):

This actually is one of the accepted uses of the "favorites" feature. With respect, your interpretation takes the name "favorites" a bit too literally; it's really more like "SO internal server-side bookmarks."

I suspect that having a second queue of "temporary favorites" would lead to more confusion than it's worth.

Comment: Well if it was called *temporary favourites* I admit it would be very confusing. But if it was called *save for later revisit* would make it a much better understood functionality with a lot less confusion and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

Favourites are by design immutable.
And from an UI perspective no one would associate a star with *add to answer later list*.

[Answer Later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/add-answer-later-tab) or Save For Later whatever the name **I need a *tick-or-mark-this-question-because-I-can't-answer-it-right-now* option**.
In the meantime I am using temporary comment reminders to track them.

Answer (score 1):

Now that it's called "Bookmarks" and not "Favorites" anymore, you can safely bookmark a question you want to visit later without marking it in any way as favorite.

Kind of status-completed-via-wording change.