# Viewing inbox should unmark read items rather than all items

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get an option to stop the global inbox from marking everything as read?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read)

In the SE dropdown inbox list, when you view it, all unread comments/answers get toggled to 'read' if you view one of them. Is there a way (of course there is; is there any support behind...) to make this per item rather than global? To set to read by comment/answer instead of all at once?

My reasons are duplicated in [Can we get an option to stop the global inbox from marking everything as read?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read) but somehow the answer interpreted that question as simply asking for this as a preference. I am asking for this as *the* way to do things. Similar to how in RSS or news group readers you know what you've attended to and what not attended to.

Comment: "I'd like it if we could have a setting whereby we have to either explicitly say to mark an item as read, or at least click on the item before it gets marked. This is probably best as a preference, since some folks in chat didn't see this as a problem." is how the other question ends, so the question was in fact asking for, and preferring, that the solution was a preference setting.

Comment: +1 I don't see a reason why anyone would want all items to be marked as read just because they showed up once in a brief listing of them. I'd consider it a defect if my RSS reader did that.

Comment: This was implemented by the [recent inbox improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/335251). I'm updating the duplicates list to point to that post as well.