# Problems with my inbox: Can we improve the inbox?

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Viewing inbox should unmark read items rather than all items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87261/viewing-inbox-should-unmark-read-items-rather-than-all-items)

I don't know if this is a duplicate, but I know it's an issue I've been having for some time.

See, when I go to bed, and I get up in the morning and log on to my stackexchange accounts, what happens is there is usually about 23 in my inbox or something. So, I click on the little red dot to view my messages, click on the first message I want to see, and when I click on the inbox, none of them are highlighted anymore. This means I don't know where the messages I haven't read yet end, or when the ones I have already read(quite some time before) begin.

Basically, with the current inbox, once you take a look, it assumes you have seen all your responses.

My feature-request is, can we have it so that the inbox highlights all messages that haven't been read? Like a regular email inbox, so that all unread messages remain highlighted, and the little red ball will slowly go from 23 to 22 to 21 to 20 as I read each message individually. This should ease me searching for the ones which I have read, and trying to distinguish it from the ones which I haven't.

Is this possible please? Comments...

Comment: Since this has been closed, can people provide ideas via comments(I will see them in my inbox!)

Comment: How about if we provide ideas on the duplicate question, instead?

Comment: How do we do that?