# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ notification shouldn't disappear

Tags: discussion, notifications, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Viewing inbox should unmark read items rather than all items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87261/viewing-inbox-should-unmark-read-items-rather-than-all-items)

When something "interesting" happens, the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ gets overlaid with a number indicating the number of interesting things there are.  You can then click on it to see those interesting things.  However, if you click on one of the interesting links, the number goes away and the interesting links are no longer available.

This is less than ideal.

I'd like to be able to review all of those things.  It seems like this is the intention, but the implementation doesn't allow for that to actually happen.

In addition, I can't find anywhere else where these interesting things are listed, though it's easily possible that I just can't find it.

What can be done about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing inbox should unmark read items rather than all items](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87261/viewing-inbox-should-unmark-read-items-rather-than-all-items), [Can we get an option to stop the global inbox from marking everything as read?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you click on the Stack Exchange link, you bring it back, but it's displaying something different than notifications.  Click on "inbox" and you'll see your latest notifications.

I usually click on the dropdown once, then middle-click on all the interesting notifications, opening each in a new tab, so I can deal with them one by one.  Opening in a new tab doesn't make the dropdown go away, so it also solves the problem you describe.

But the canonical solution is to click the dropdown, and select "inbox".

Comment: Boy, do I feel like an idiot.

Comment: @wfaulk Don't feel bad, it took me a *long* time to realize it as well.  It's not intuitive...

Comment: It'd sure be nice if it defaulted to Inbox.

Comment: @Lance I agree.  The feature request for that hasn't been declined, but it hasn't been accepted or sompleted either: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86342/can-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-default-to-inbox-rather-tha