# Inbox notification goes away faster than I want it to

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Viewing inbox should unmark read items rather than all items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87261/viewing-inbox-should-unmark-read-items-rather-than-all-items)

Sometimes I will have 3 or 4 new things in my inbox, and I am happy that I can see the red number and that the new things are bold.

However, when I open the menu and click any one of them, they all become marked as "read." I wish the ones I haven't seen yet to remain "unread" so that I can browse to them without having to remember which ones are new.

Comment: I solve this by opening these links in a new browser tab each.

Comment: Note that all of your inbox items are still there.  You just have to click the inbox link in the dropdown.

Comment: Or the **responses** tab of your profile page.

Comment: I do know they're there. I just wish the remaining unclicked links would stay marked as unread. So for instance, just now when I noticed you'd responded, I had 3 responses pending. I clicked yours. Now I have to remember which the other 2 were.