# I'd like to be able to mark answer or comment as unread in the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange inbox

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get an option to stop the global inbox from marking everything as read?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read)

Is there a way to mark an answer or comment in Stack Overflow as unread?  Many times, I'll read something in my inbox, and get interrupted at work and forget about someone's reply.  If not, may I suggest an enhancement, and have the default be unread if viewed.  The only way I think it should be automatically marked as read is if you reply to a comment, mark an answer as "the answer" or edit something after that comment/answer was given by someone else.  But still have a button that says you read it.

Comment: See also [Can we get an option to stop the global inbox from marking everything as read?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72440) (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEI [historically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read/72441#72441) has not implemented preferences or user options. I have a suggestion though: instead of having some option to turn on, just make the inbox only mark things as read if you click on them.

This would solve a couple issues:

1. Clicking the inbox and deciding to deal with it later - if clicking a link is required to dismiss it, it's harder to forget about it since the red notification will still be there next time you log in.
2. When you open the inbox and click on the first notification, it's easy to miss the later ones. This can be a problem even when opening in new tabs.

Comment: I like that idear!  How do we submit an feature request?  Or do they proactively search for those tagged with "feature-request"?