# Is there a way to unfollow upvote notifications?

Tags: support, reputation, notifications, up-votes

When visiting a Stack Exchange site, I usually find myself distracted by an upvote on *any* of my questions or answers. In the past, it generated a red notification bubble in the top left of the page.

I have about 4,000-5,000 reputation points. Surely this feature must disturb people who have higher reputation more than it bothers me. No?

I deem another question to be very similar, *[Is there a way to unfollow notifications on a particular post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142281/is-there-a-way-to-unfollow-notifications-on-a-particular-post)*. However (i) it didn't ask about upvotes specifically and (ii) it's four years old now.

Comment: *"Surely this feature must disturb people who have higher reputation more than it bothers me."* [no, not really](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DBWG9.png) (at the top)

Comment: @Memor-X good point. Not everyone embraces "Inbox Zero". :)