# inbox items are marked as read when I don't read them

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get an option to stop the global inbox from marking everything as read?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read)

If I have more than one item in my inbox, they are all marked as read as soon as I open my inbox.

Shouldn't it only mark items as read when I actually read them?

Comment: Funny, I feel like I have the exact opposite problem!

Comment: it's frustrating because I may have 5 new messages and as soon as I click on one, they all go to "read" so I loose track of which ones are new.