# Closing the global inbox removes the notifications indicator

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

When I see the red "new inbox items" indicator in the MultiCollider, I tend to check them out pretty quickly. When I see the blue "new notifications" indicator, I sometimes decide to hold off/save them for later. As a result, I often have some unread notifications hanging around when I visit my inbox.

Most of the time, but not always, checking and closing my inbox removes all indicators from the MultiCollider, even if I have unread notifications. I think I should still see a blue circle, but I actually see the SE logo.

This happens for me on multiple recent versions of Firefox, both at work and at home.

(This is similar to [Can we get an option to stop the global inbox from marking everything as read?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read) but that one is about opening the inbox removing the inbox indicator, whereas this one is about finishing a visit to the inbox removing the inbox **and notification** indicators.)

Update:
Actually, merely *checking* the inbox isn't enough to destroy notification indicators. If I open the inbox and then visit a post that's related to an inbox post, I still see the blue circle, as expected. It's only after I return to the original tab and close the MultiCollider pop-out that the indicator disappears. I haven't used Fiddler or anything to see exactly why, but I'd be happy to do so if someone would explain how. I've updated my wording elsewhere in this post accordingly.