# Reading notification on website should clear native Android notification

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, android-app

I think it would be nice if you read an inbox notification on the desktop version of the site, it should dismiss the native Android notification in the system tray. It seems kind of weird when I come back to my phone an hour later, and find a bunch of notifications I thought a dealt with... and come to find out I really did deal with them.

Comment: And visa-versa ideally. i.e. I read the notification on android. This should stop the notification appearing on the website.

Comment: @georgeduckett It seems like that's already implemented. If you read a notification from within the Android app, the red notification symbol on the site vanishes already. That's what happened with your comment notification at least...

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're quite right. Possibly I already had it open or had 2 notifications or something.

Comment: I've just had it happen again. I received a notification in the app. Wanted to edit my comment so I opened it in the browser and was greeted with the same 2 notifications.

Comment: This would increase the data transfer for Notification exactly 2 times.

Comment: @VenomVendor I don't think it would. When you read the global inbox on the website it marks all notifications as read. It seems like there needs to be one push message to the phone that simply says "read all notifications on website and clear notification from tray". That would be a very small push message without the need to push anything twice.

Comment: I haven't noticed working of notifications properly, does one click clear all pending notifications or clears only clicked notification?

Comment: @VenomVendor Are we talking about the clearing of the native notification in the notification tray being cleared when you read the notifications on the desktop version of the website?

Comment: my last comment was about desktop version.

Comment: @VenomVendor ah okay. On the desktop site, when you click and open the notification window, all notifications are marked read. There [was a request to change this behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read) but it was declined by Jeff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was supposed to be available in an earlier version.  Research led me to a deployment issue around the push notification service.  It should be fixed now - if you read your inbox on the website it will clear the notification on your android device.

Comment: Bah! I didn't realize this was an answer to this question... now to wait for another notification.

Comment: Here's a test comment - let's see if it works.

Comment: Huzzah, looks good! Thanks!

Comment: Works on my phone :)