# Where can I download my user data? (GDPR data portability)

Tags: discussion, gdpr

The GDPR (not to be confused with GDFR) does mandate data portability, which even Instagram listened to by introducing a user archive download feature.

Does the Stack Exchange Network also have such a feature?

[Jeff Atwood: “We generally don't do preferences”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72441/379894)

Gladly, this philosophy does not apply to Discourse, but it would be good if we could download our user data.

Comment: What do you consider to be your *user data*? Please be precise.

Comment: FYI GDPR only applies to *personal* data, and you can download it in your user preferences.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I'm probably going blind or I am not privileged but where in my user preferences can I download my personal data? I need something with a red free hand circle ...

Comment: @rene [/users/preferences/current](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog You mean the personal prediction data? That is not  the same as user data and not the same I presume what you get from the GDPR request form?

Comment: @rene Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog unforgivable ;)

Answer (score 13):

While we've always made sure you have access to the data we collect on you in various places, our legal pages do now include a [GDPR Request](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request) page where you can export, erase, or restrict your data in a simple form that covers everything.

Comment: Does this data covers all stackexchange sites or do we have to do this individually?

Comment: It is a network-wide request. It is not possible to limit it per-site.

Comment: Very weird: I received a small JSON file which contains my mail address, Account Id and Account creation date. No answers, no votes, no questions, no nothing...