# "Save For Later" feature

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save questions to visit later, but not exactly 'favourite' them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69346/save-questions-to-visit-later-but-not-exactly-favourite-them)

One frequent position I find myself in is reading a question I'm interested in, not knowing the answer, and wanting to come back and read the responses later. Usually to do this, I favorite the particular question. Once I read the answer, I go in and un-favorite. This is honestly the ideal form of functionality and at the beginning of Stack Overflow, I had no issue with it.

But as my **real** favorite list grows, it's cumbersome to use. I realize that I can sort by most recent, but for those questions that don't get answered for days/weeks/months it makes it difficult to go back and un-favorite them.

Am I the only one who would enjoy this feature?

Comment: Is that your question? or are you asking for some new feature?

Comment: Asking for the new feature mainly, curious if other people have a similar desire.

Comment: This is a duplicate of most of the posts in the related list, I just picked [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69346/save-questions-to-visit-later-but-not-exactly-favourite-them)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. Nothing popped up when I first added it. I've flagged it for moderator deletion though.

Answer (score 1):

> But as my **real** favorite list grows, it's cumbersome to use

What do you think would happen to your "saved for later" list if this were to be implemented?

I suggest you try to organize your favorites better

Comment: Perhaps I'm a luddite but I'm not sure how to "organize" my favorites at all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use SO favorite system.

I use Favorites toolbar in Chrome, which can't contain too many entries... well, since it's a toolbar and doesn't have much space anyway.

Also, you can't forget about it if it's right in front of your eyes.

Comment: I'll check this out for the time being. I realize I don't have to use SO for this feature, but streamlining this process on the site would be a major boon.