# Can I mark some Stack Overflow questions and view them later?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save questions to visit later, but not exactly 'favourite' them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69346/save-questions-to-visit-later-but-not-exactly-favourite-them)

Sometimes I want to follow some questions until they are answered and beyond that.

How can I follow up a list of some wanted questions in Stack Overflow?

Comment: This belongs on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: So, you're asking for more than one list of favourites?

Answer (score 6):

Click the star to make the question a favourite. On your user page click the favourites tab to see your favourites.

[image: screenshot showing favourites icon]

Answer (score 1):

Marking the questions as 'Favorite' is the only method as far as I know.