# Why did I score points for an answer which I didn't post?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit a question (from other user) and get +2 rep ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77505/edit-a-question-from-other-user-and-get-2-rep)

This has been a strange behavior, I don't know its a **feature**  or a **bug**.

First this is the link to the Question I am talking about

[Can I mark some Stack Overflow questions and view them later?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81116/154790)

**Now the problem.**

On that question a user [posted an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81116/can-i-mark-some-stackoverflow-questions-and-view-them-later/81117#81117). Later I [edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/81117/revisions) (suggested) the answer and added a picture to make answer more helpful.

[image: Answer's Image]

Now today when I viewed my recent activities summary, I saw that I have earned **2pts** for that answer (see screen shot below).

[image: Screen shot of my points]

So, I don't know if this is a feature or a bug. I haven't any mention of such behavior in FAQ's. Also I have done many edits on SO and never got any points for that :( so why now.

---

Now, **if this is a bug i would like to suggest to make it a feature**. it would be good to get some points for doing some contribution by editing the answer.

(That's why I have added both <kbd>feature-request</kbd> and <kbd>bug</kbd> tags to this question)

---

I didn't found any similar question previously asked (may be I'm using wrong keywords)

Answer (score 1):

If you edit a question while you have under 2K rep and your edit is approved, you are given 2 points.