# Is there any facility to mark questions as Followups or Flag to look at flagged questions later beside favorites

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any facility in SO whereby I can mark the questions as flagged or follow in the future just like favorites?

But favorites is another thing, I mean I will only mark those questions favorites which are ever green and I can read any time.

But for flagged, I mean suppose I am looking for backup scripts and there are five SO questions which I find interesting to look at them later so that I can get my answer. But marking them favorite mixes all other questions.

Just like we have emails to be marked with various flags.

Something like favorites but twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flag weight audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84757/flag-weight-audit)

Comment: i think thats totally different , by flaging , i just mean a way of marking questions to read later just like favorites , it has nothing to do with weights , or reputation

Comment: @Bobby: He doesn't mean *that* kind of flagging. I've seen that confusion a couple of times here with users meaning "flagging" in a completely different sense than the kind we raise for moderator attention.

Comment: This is a better duplicate: [Save questions to visit later, but not exactly 'favourite' them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69346/save-questions-to-visit-later-but-not-exactly-favourite-them). But this feature request/discussion has transpired several times here. A search will turn up numerous hits.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Oh. @Mirror51: In that case, ignore my vote, sorry.

Comment: I'd like to see the option to colour code favourites, but as it stands, the only option seems to be manage it yourself in some other way (add it to browser favourites, have links on your profile, subscribe to question RSS feeds, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with using Favorites?

I don't mean that as a rhetorical question either :-)

What you are suggesting is *incredibly* similar to the existing favorites feature and while I completely agree that being able to track questions like that would be awesome, I don't think that having two identical but distinct lists is that good solution (e.g. "Favorites", for following questions and "Marked", for following up later - the only difference would be the name).

It would be better to improve favorites to make it easier to organise "Favorited" questions, I'm thinking something along the lines of "Group by tag" view... somehow... (I'll let someone smarter than me figure out how that one might work)

So I suppose I'm really asking "How could favorites be improved so that it does the same thing?"

Comment: i like the group by tag idea , for now i am just mixing all i favorites and then remove it