# Timed reminders for action, attached to questions

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to see a feature in which I can get an inbox notification from myself in a set number of hours/days, attached to a particular question. For example, I might ask someone to improve a post, or might be interested in seeing what new answers have come in (sometimes this will trigger an inbox response, sometimes it won't, depending on whether I've answered/commented/edited and what form the response actions took). Today I promised a bounty on someone's question, but need to wait for a couple of days before it can be offered.

For the time being I paste a question URL into my online calendar, but it would save me some hassle for this to be a bit more integrated. Likewise I sometimes ask an OP to remind me "in a couple of days" but it would be nice to be able to be a bit more proactive.

What you reckon?

Comment: Related: [Save questions to visit later, but not exactly 'favourite' them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69346/save-questions-to-visit-later-but-not-exactly-favourite-them)

Comment: I favorite the question.  There's a sort for most recent at the top.

Comment: That's certainly one solution, but I sense the same issue that is raised in response to @ShaDowWizArd's link - I use favourites for questions that are related to my work/interests, rather than questions that I'd like to follow up for the OP's benefit. A 'save for later' would be good, if a timed message isn't of widespread interest.