# how to make a question favorite?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)

I want to make some questions my favorite and refer them later

Comment: Voted to close as dupe, even though this question has better freehand circles.

Comment: Jon B, are there any problems with my freehand circles? Cretin!

Answer (score 8):

You just click the star underneath the vote count / vote arrows in the question.

[Mark As Favorite http://www.sqeq.com/image/MSO_MarkFavorite.jpg](http://www.sqeq.com/image/MSO_MarkFavorite.jpg)

If that star is colored yellow for you then that question has been marked as a favorite.  Click it again to unmark it.  The number underneath indicates how many people have marked it as a favorite

[Mark As Favorite http://www.sqeq.com/image/MSO_MarkFavorite2.jpg](http://www.sqeq.com/image/MSO_MarkFavorite2.jpg)

To review your list of favorites click the Favorites tab when viewing your user profile.

Comment: +1 for freehand circles _and_ text.