# save a question on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)

Hello,

Is it possible to save a php question on stackoverflow?  I do some searching and find my answer, then I would like to save that somehow into my user area so I don't have to search again for it...

Is this possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 6):

Click on the star symbol under the question upvotes counter. That will add the question to your "favourites"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, simply click the "star" icon to add it to your favorites.