# Is there a "add to favorites" option for questions in Stack Overflow (and sister sites)?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Not sure if this question falls in "stackoverflow". Please move to right forum if it does not.

Is there any options to have a list of "favorite" questions (or some other list), where I can quickly add questions/answers that I might want to refer to later but not have to search for?

Comment: Vote to close. I think the answer is here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions

Comment: How come you were not sure if this question was asked in the right place?

Comment: @Arjan : it got migrated from SO to meta-SO

Comment: I know, @M'vy, but where did the FAQ fail, so Jus12 couldn't decide to post in the right place right away?

Comment: @Arjan : oh well! Didn't understand you point sorry.

Comment: @Arjan : my bad

Answer (score 1):

Click on a start next to the question to add it to your favourite.

See your list of favourited questions on the favourite tab of your user page.

Comment: Well it is only a partial solution. I would prefer to keep two types of favorites (or rather, not even call the second type as 'favorite'). The first type is public info, while the second type is similar to 'save to private list', where I can refer to it anytime, without worrying about who else can see what I have saved to this list.

Comment: Also, it only favorites questions. What I really need is to jump directly to answers.