# BookMarking Liked-Useful pages, or associate with my StackOverflow Profile

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)
>   [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)

I am using StackOverFlow on regular basis for past 6 months. I want to know if there is any option to bookmark some pages, which I might want to refer later. basically Can I associate some pages which might refer later to my profile, so that it will be easier for me to search ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work), [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bookmark the questions using the favorite button, if that is what you are looking for. Even if you like the answer, the process is the same. You need to favorite the question.

Here is how to do it.

If you like the question/answers so much and falling head over heels for it, follow the star. Trust me, this star is bigger than the brightest star. You won't miss it. It is right next to the question on the left hand side.

Keep your hands on the mouse steady, *real steady*... otherwise you might end up downvoting your favorite question. As **@Cody** had pointed out in the comments, you can certainly undo the downvoting but you will still end up getting a *`Critic`* badge, if that is your first downvote even if you undo it.

[image: Look for the star]

Once you click on the star, it will show up on the favorites tab in your user profile.

[image: Favorites tab]

Looks like you don't have any favorite question/answer at Meta SO at this time.

[image: Favorites tooltip]

Comment: faster and with images! :o

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: *"Keep your hands on the mouse steady, real steady... otherwise you might end up downvoting your favorite question."* I know this is a joke, but just to be clear: you can always "undo" an accidental vote by clicking on the arrow again.

Comment: @Cody: Yes, it was a joke. I have added more info to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the star under the voting buttons to the left of a question's text toggles the question's **favorite** status. On your profile screen (reached by clicking your username in the header), at the very top right is a `favorites` button which takes you to a screen showing all your currently favorited questions.