# What is the use of "This is a favorite question (click again to undo)"?

Tags: support, questions, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

I saw a star that appears at the bottom of  my question. When I point my mouse on it, I am getting a message **This is a favorite question (click again to undo)**.

How it will be useful to me?

Comment: See [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This adds the question to your favourites (or removes it) if you click it; they can be viewed on a tab on your profile. This more or less allows you to find questions you like more easily later on.

[Your SO favourites.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839280/eager-student?tab=favorites)

Actually, I think that the tooltip text is really off, and confusing. How about something like, "**Add/remove question to/from favorites.**" Just less *meh*.