# How do I use favorites in the user profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

There are many questions and answers that have helped me on Stack Overflow, and I want to know if there is a way to save them in my profile. I've installed the Stack Overflow toolbar in Firefox, and I see there is a Favorites tab in my user profile.

Is this for adding questions by other users that I want to keep? If so, how is this done?  Otherwise, what is favorites used for? I've looked over "questions with similar titles," but they are not for the Favorites feature in the user profile; at least, I couldn't find one after several attempts typing in the "title" textbox.

Answer (score 0):

http://phpcode.eu/images/1317817494.pnghttp://phpcode.eu/images/1317817583.png

And you can access them via

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/USERID?tab=favorites
```